# populating form with mysql data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hopefully someone can help with my problem, I have a database using MySQL and I have a form that posts to the database, this all works fine.

I have created a customer look up form using HTML and PHP that echos a table and then the table is filled with the MySQL data, again this all works OK.

My problem is that I would like to click the table row or text in that row which ever and open it in a HTML form and include all the data from the row in the MySQL database.

```
<div id="content">
<h3>Customer Lookup</h3>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","repairsdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Landline</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['addressl1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['landline'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['businessname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<FORM>
</FORM>
</div>
```

New Code

```
<h3>Customer Lookup</h3>
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","repairsdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Landline</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='/repairdb/customer_form.php?customerid=" . $row['customerid'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['addressl1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['landline'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

customer_form.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","repairsdb");
if( isset( $_GET['customerid'] ) ) {
  $customerid = $_GET['customerid'];
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers where customerid = " . $customerid . " Limit 1");

?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="$result['firstname']" />
  <input type="text" name="surname" value="$result['surname']" />
  <input type="text" name="addressl1" value="$result['addressl1']" />
  <input type="text" name="postcode" value="$result['postcode']" />
  <input type="text" name="landline" value="$result['landline']" />
  <input type="text" name="mobile" value="$result['mobile']" />
  <input type="text" name="businessname" value="$result['businessname']" />
</form>
```

Comment: Whats the name of the primarly key in `customers` table?

Comment: man you got a whole lot ways to go from that requirement, maybe setup a popup form (i'm not really good at ux), mostly by js, populate the fields, then just do a normal form submission, then the usual stuff mysql connection and the rest is straightforward

Comment: And what is the problem with your code ?

Comment: HINT : you can call ajax on click of the row and send id of the row as parameter. fetch the result as html form and put it into your container.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it would just be a case of adding a link to the table row, and passing the primary key (ID, for example), so that you can make a new MySQL query, returning the data for that row in a new page. Then echo the data into a form, similar to how you are doing it here.

Comment: @Gavin : `My problem is` - this is not a problem, this is called `Requirement`...Problem is when you code something and you are not getting desired output!!

Comment: the primary key is customerid set to an int that auto increments

Comment: @user1100149 thanks for you comment, struggling to get my head round this, could you show me some sample code or point my in the direction of an article showing this

Comment: @user1100149 sorry for the delay getting back to you, I have edited my original post with update code, I think I have placed the code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easiest way to do this would be to open the form in a new page.** So to do this we would start by adding a link to your table.

I'm going to assume that in your database you have an **unique ID** for each customer - we will use this in the link:

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='/customer_form.php?customer_id=" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['addressl1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['landline'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['businessname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

As you can see I have named the new page *customer_form.php*. And we will **pass the ID to this page via the URL**, like so.

```
www.example.com/customer_form.php?customer_id=3
```

In your new *customer_form.php* page you will first need to **retrieve the ID** from the URL.

```
if( isset( $_GET['customer_id'] ) ) {
  $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
}
```

Then we will modify this block of code a little more to retrieve the customer from the database, using the ID, and then we can add this data to a new form.

```
if( isset( $_GET['customer_id'] ) ) {
  $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers where ID = " . $customer_id . " Limit 1");

  echo '
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="'. $result['firstname'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="'. $result['surname'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="addressl1" value="'. $result['addressl1'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="'. $result['postcode'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="landline" value="'. $result['landline'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="mobile" value="'. $result['mobile'] .'" />
    <input type="text" name="businessname" value="'. $result['businessname'] .'" />
  </form>
  ';
}
```

You could do it other ways, in a pop up window, or even on the same page using JavaScript. But this is the least complicated.

I should note that the SQL query I wrote would be vulnerable to SQL injection, since it takes a value from the address bar and injects it directly into the query. But it's a little outside of the scope of the question, so I suggest you look it up if interested.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I have tried the code and when I click on the firstname I get an 404 error, my unique ID is "customerid", any ideas why I receive the 404 error?

Comment: A 404 Error means the page doesn't exist. Or that your link is incorrect. The important bit here is the link to customer_form.php (if that's what you've called it - you can call it whatever you like). For now, make sure that the link and the filename match, and that the file is in the correct directory. In fact, what you could try, is removing the leading slash from the link, like so: `<a href='customer_form.php?customer_id=" . $row['ID'] . "'>`, as that could be the culprit, depending on your server setup. (This all assumes you have no URL Rewriting setup!)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I sorted the 404 error but when the page loads the textbox has $result['firstname']

Comment: It's actually displaying the text *$result['firstname']* in the input box? I would assume from this that the form is not being echoed. Or that you have your quotation marks incorrect somewhere. Which is causing your PHP variable to be displayed as a string, rather than a variable.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this would work...

use clicks on link (selects something in)

then - jqueryAJAX POSTs FORM

then - php processPOST

then - mysql getDataFrom DB

then - php process MYSQL results && echo $jsoResults

then - jqueryAJAX process results open new Form with inputs populated...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort the errors, I have posted the code for anyone having the same problem. I have answered this question myself only for the reason so I can post the final code, but the credit has to go to @user1100149 and also a chap on YouTube.

[Link to youtube video editing mysql with PHP](http://youtu.be/kc1bppUlqps)

```
<?php 
 // Connects to Our Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("repairsdb") or die(mysql_error()); 

    if(!isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = $_GET[customerid]";
        $result = mysql_query($q);
        $person = mysql_fetch_array($result)or die (mysql_error()); 
    }
?>
<form name="submit_customer" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <div id="frcol3">
      <fieldset>
      <label id="label" for="webaddress">Business</label>
        <input name="businessname" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['businessname']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input class="inputBox" type="text" name="firstname" id="" value="<?php echo $person['firstname']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="Surname">Surname</label>
        <input name="surname" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['surname']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="landline">Telephone No.</label>
        <input name="landline" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['landline']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="mobile">Mobile No.</label>
        <input name="mobile" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['mobile']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['email']; ?>" />


      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="frcol2">
      <fieldset>
        <label id="label" for="webaddress">Web Address</label>
        <input name="webaddress" type="text" class="inputBox" id=""  value="<?php echo $person['webaddress']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="addressl1">Address Line 1</label>
        <input name="addressl1" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['addressl1']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="addressl2">Address Line 2</label>
        <input name="addressl2" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['addressl2']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="town">Town</label>
        <input name="town" type="text" class="inputBox" id="" value="<?php echo $person['town']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="county">County</label>
        <input name="county" type="text" id="" class="inputBox"  value="<?php echo $person['county']; ?>" />
        <label id="label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input name="postcode" type="text" id="" class="inputBox"  value="<?php echo $person['postcode']; ?>" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="frcol1">
      <textarea name="notes" id="notes" placeholder="<?php echo $person['notes']; ?>" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="customerid" value="<?php echo $_GET['customerid']; ?>" />

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="" class=" button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```